# Assembly Language Beginner Division

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I never programmed before but I'm learning the logic portion of Assembly Language.

How would I print the remainder of, 10 divided by 3? Sounds really simple but I'm not very good at it. I'll show you my attempt

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
val1 WORD 10
val2 WORD 3

.code    
mov ax, val1
div ax, val2
mov finalVal, ax
call DumpRegs

exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Please tell me what i did wrong.. and how to get the remainder (which would be 1)

Comment: As a side note: If you have never done any coding before, **assembly is not a good place to start**. I would try something simpler, like Java or Python, and then work my way up from there.

Comment: - or down, as it were :)

Comment: I don't think `div ax, val2` will assemble. Try just `div val2` - the `ax` is implicit.

Comment: Before doing the divide, set dx to zero (xor dx,dx). After the divide, ax gets the quotient, and dx gets the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

**DIV**

Unsigned divide AX by r/m8, with result stored in AL = Quotient, AH = Remainder.

Unsigned divide DX:AX by r/m16, with result stored in AX = Quotient, DX = Remainder.

Unsigned divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with result stored in EAX = Quotient, EDX = Remainder.

```
...
xor dx,dx
mov ax,val1
mov bx,val2
div bx
mov finalVal,dx ;Remainder
...
```